# Ejecutar y obtener valor retornado por un SP de MYSQL en PHP (Conexión PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo, stored-procedure

Me gustaria saber si alguien podría indicarme como ejecutar un procedimiento en PHP y capturar el valor retornado por este, siendo que la conexión que realizo es PDO.

Mi código de conexión de PHP es este:

```html
class conexion{

    private $servidor = "localhost";
    private $usuario = "root";
    private $password = "Alex1234";
    private $conexion;

    function  __construct(){

        try{

            $this->conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servidor;dbname=casas_rincon_guate", $this->usuario, $this->password);
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOException $e){
    
            return "Falla de conexion".$e;
    
        }

    }

    public function ejecutar($sql){

        $this->conexion->exec($sql);
        return $this->conexion->lastInsertId();

    }

    public function consultar($sql){

        $sentencia = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        $sentencia->execute();

        return $sentencia->fetchAll();

    }

    public function contar($sql)
    {

        $sentencia = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        $sentencia->execute();

        return $sentencia->rowCount();
    }
```

Mi procedimiento almacenado:

```html
 delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE HOLA (IN EMAIL VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN

    
    IF exists (SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE Email_Usuario = EMAIL) Then return true;
    ELSE return false;
    END IF;

END//
delimiter ;
```

Quisiera saber como llamar a dicha función desde PHP y capturar el false o true que returna el procedimiento.

Así mismo, me gustaria como capturar el valor de una variable tipo OUT definida en un procedimiento desde PHP.

Gracias de antemano.

EDICION:

```html
$conexion = new conexion();

$correo = '123@gmail.com';

$sql = "CALL HOLA('$correo')";

$resultado = $conexion->consultar($sql);


if ($resultado == "1") {

                                                    echo "existe";
                                                } else {


                                                    echo "no existe";
                                                };
```

Comment: Cuando llamas a un SP desde PHP, lo haces igual que si hicieses la consulta. El resultado será un resultset con las filas que podes recorrer normalmente o un resultset vacío en caso de no encontrar coincidencias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera.

MySQL:

```
/* creo la tabla y le cargo un par de usuarios */
drop table if exists USUARIO;
create table USUARIO (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    usuario varchar(20) not null,
    Email_Usuario varchar(20) not null,
    primary key (id),
    constraint ui_email unique (Email_Usuario)
)engine="InnoDB";
insert into USUARIO values 
    (null, "usu1", "usu1@rio.com"),
    (null, "usu2", "usu2@rio.com"),
    (null, "usu3", "usu3@rio.com");

/* creo el procedimiento y la función */

drop procedure if exists HOLA;
drop function if exists HOLA; -- no es recomendable repetir nombres

delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE HOLA (IN EMAIL VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    declare existe tinyint;
    set existe = (SELECT count(id) FROM USUARIO WHERE Email_Usuario = EMAIL);
    
    IF (existe = 1) Then
        select true as existe;
    ELSE
        select false as existe;
    END IF;

END//

create function HOLA(EMAIL varchar(20)) returns int
begin
    declare existe tinyint;
    set existe = (SELECT count(id) FROM USUARIO WHERE Email_Usuario = EMAIL);
    
    IF (existe = 1) Then
        return 1;
    ELSE
        return 0;
    END IF;
end //
delimiter ;
```

PHP:

```
$email1 = "usu1@rio.com";
$email2 = "usu9@rio.com";

$consulta = "call HOLA('$email1')";
$resultado = $conexion->consultar($consulta);
if ($resultado === false) { echo "error"; }
$existe = $conexion->resultado->fetch_assoc();
echo "$email1: ";print_r($existe);

echo "<br>";
$consulta = "call HOLA('$email2')";
$resultado = $conexion->consultar($consulta);
if ($resultado === false) { echo "error"; }
$existe = $conexion->resultado->fetch_assoc();
echo "$email2: "; print_r($existe);

echo "<br>";
$consulta = "select HOLA('$email1')";
$resultado = $conexion->consultar($consulta);
if ($resultado === false) { echo "error"; }
$existe = $conexion->resultado->fetch_assoc();
echo "$email1: "; print_r($existe);

echo "<br>";
$consulta = "select HOLA('$email2')";
$resultado = $conexion->consultar($consulta);
if ($resultado === false) { echo "error"; }
$existe = $conexion->resultado->fetch_assoc();
echo "$email2: "; print_r($existe);
```

Pruebas MySQL:

```
/* hago las llamadas tanto para un correo existente como para uno inexistente y estos son los resultados: */
mysql> call HOLA("usu1@rio.com");
+--------+
| existe |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> call HOLA("usu9@rio.com");
+--------+
| existe |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> select HOLA("usu1@rio.com");
+----------------------+
| HOLA("usu1@rio.com") |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select HOLA("usu9@rio.com");
+----------------------+
| HOLA("usu9@rio.com") |
+----------------------+
|                    0 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Pruebas PHP:

```
usu1@rio.com: Array ( [existe] => 1 )
usu9@rio.com: Array ( [existe] => 0 )
usu1@rio.com: Array ( [HOLA('usu1@rio.com')] => 1 )
usu9@rio.com: Array ( [HOLA('usu9@rio.com')] => 0 )
```

Comment: Una pregunta, si uso el método consultar no devolvería un conjunto de resultados y no true o false? Y si devuelve lo esperado, el SP devuelve 1, 0 o True, False?

Comment: si te fijas en el código que puse, si encuentra el email te devuelve true (`select true as existe`) y si no te devuelve false (`select false as existe`).

Comment: Pero devuelve un 1, 0 o True, False? Es que probé el procedimiento desde MYSQL y lo que devuelve es un numero, entonces en PHP también me va a capturar el int no?

Comment: Te devuelve 1 si existe, 0 si no existe.

Comment: No funciona bro. Me indica que no existe cuando si existe

Comment: Probe directamente con la misma llamada que hago en MYSQL y en este me devuelve que existe mientras en PHP me devuelve que no

Comment: @AlexanderQuinteros fijate que amplié mi respuesta para darte otra alternativa mas apropiada, según mi punto de vista, que es usar una función

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de realizar la función, pero necesito usar SP ya que es un requerimiento del proyecto en el que trabajo

Comment: Todo bien. PHP lo único que hace es recoger el resultado de la consulta y dejar que lo manejes conforme a tus necesidades. La consulta está bien formada y funciona correctamente. Cómo estás haciendo la comparación en PHP? Esto devuelve 1 o 0, así que tenes que comparar contra 1 (== "1") o contra 0 (== "0")

Comment: Revisa la edición de la pregunta, ahí coloque el código de lo que estoy ejecutando

Comment: Esta línea: `$sql = "CALL HOLA('$correo')";` debería ser: `$sql = "CALL HOLA($correo)";`. Las comillas simples.

Comment: Me marca error, por que me pasa la variable a SQL como un texto. Las comillas van para que el dato salga CALL HOLA('123@gmail.com') y no como CALL HOLA123@gmail.com)

Comment: Si si, disculpa. Mira, reedité toda la respuesta. Te muestro el código de MySQL, el de PHP, y los resultados de ambos.